# String array without double quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I want to convert string array to another array without quotes in javascript

```
[
  "L.latLng(30.709455,76.688576)",
  "L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)",
  "L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)",
  "L.latLng(30.70947,76.6886)",
  "L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)"
];
```

Expected result:

```
[
  L.latLng(30.709455, 76.688576),
  L.latLng(30.709461, 76.68856),
  L.latLng(30.709461, 76.68856),
  L.latLng(30.70947, 76.6886),
  L.latLng(30.709461, 76.68856)
];
```

Comment: It cannot be unless `L.latLng` is a function and that returns a datatype

Comment: may understanding what's a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) will help.

Comment: xy question, why is your array like that in the first place?

Comment: You could use `eval` to execute the JavaScript expression, but this brings lots of security risks if the input cannot be trusted

Comment: @madalinivascu that's the java Arraylist I am getting. And I want to use that list in the Leaflet module.

Comment: can you provide the java code?

Comment: @Ferrybig  it worked. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to this problem.

## The dangerously unsafe `eval` way:

This approach directly calls `eval`, this executes any JavaScript code passed in, and thus has a lot of security problems related to this.

```
const newArray = stringArray.map(eval);
```

## `eval` with a whitelist

One way to make a call to `eval` more safe, is to use a whitelist of the allowed patterns, this makes sure code doesn't access any variables outside its intended scope.

```js
const L = {};
L.latLng = (lat, lng) => ({ lat, lng })

const stringArray = [
    "L.latLng(30.709455,76.688576)",
    "L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)",
    "L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)",
    "L.latLng(30.70947,76.6886)",
    "L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)"
];

const newArray = stringArray.map((line) => {
    if(/L\.latLng\(-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+),-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)\)/.test(line)) {
        return eval(line);
    }
    throw new Error('Invalid string specified: ' + line);
});

console.log(newArray);
```

## Custom parser per line

By having a custom parser per line, you prevent any unwanted code executing, as only save methods can be executed.

This is a step up from the exec with whitelist case, as just certain parts of the string have to be captured

```js
const L = {};
L.latLng = (lat, lng) => ({ lat, lng })

const stringArray = [
    "L.latLng(30.709455,76.688576)",
    "L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)",
    "L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)",
    "L.latLng(30.70947,76.6886)",
    "L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)"
];

const newArray = stringArray.map((line) => {
    const match = /^L\.latLng\((-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)),(-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+))\)$/.exec(line)
    if(match !== null) {
        return L.latLng(parseFloat(match[1]), parseFloat(match[2]));
    }
    throw new Error('Invalid string specified: ' + line);
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data =["L.latLng(30.709455,76.688576)", "L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)", "L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)", "L.latLng(30.70947,76.6886)", "L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)"]

var model = JSON.stringify(data);

var removeString = model.replace(/"/g,'');
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
[L.latLng(30.709455,76.688576),L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856),L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856),L.latLng(30.70947,76.6886),L.latLng(30.709461,76.68856)]
```

Comment: output will be a `String` not an `Array`.